# Can noun follow by it

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have found this sentence. 
It said 'Whatever the final answer to the water crisis may be, it is evident that within the High Plains, irrigation
water will never again be the abundant, **inexpensive resource it** was during the agricultural boom years of the
mid-twentieth century'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Whatever the final answer to the water crisis may be, it is evident*
>   *that within the High Plains, irrigation water will never again be the*
>   *abundant, inexpensive resource* [*(that/which) it was during the agricultural boom*
>   *years of the mid-twentieth century*].

It's fine.

Square brackets surround a relative clause modifying the noun phrase "abundant inexpensive resource". Note that "that" or "which" could be inserted, as shown.  Within the relative clause, "it" refers to "irrigation water".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

You can read it like this:

> ...water will never again be the ... resource **which** it was...